# Using UIWebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest with Storyboard and prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, ios7

I have a non storyboard app that has a UITableView with a bunch of cells, upon clicking a cell I push a view controller with a UIWebView, the local html file is loaded based on the cell tapped.

If this UIWebView then has other links in it, I use the UIWebView delegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest along with this code:

```
if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        //When a html link is clicked in uiwebview
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

        //Get components of url
        NSArray *urlComponents = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        //Get last component which should be wanted file name
        NSString *wantedLink = [urlComponents objectAtIndex:[urlComponents count]-1];

        //Get the url without the dot
        NSArray *fileComponents = [wantedLink componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *wantedFile = [fileComponents objectAtIndex:0];

        ALSDetailViewController *superDetail = [[ALSDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ALSProtocolDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.alsProtocolDetailViewController = superDetail;

        //Check for each wanted file name to see if it matches another file
        if ([wantedLink isEqualToString:@"VTachPulseStable.html"]) {
            //Open different protocol xib with html file name as parameter, and push the view in
            self.alsProtocolDetailViewController.title = @"Ventricular Tachycardia With Pulse";

            self.alsProtocolDetailViewController.protocolURL = wantedFile;
            self.alsProtocolDetailViewController.protocolSubTitle = @"Stable Without Decompensation";

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.alsProtocolDetailViewController animated:YES];

            return NO;
        }
    }
```

This code is from my working old non-storyboard app.

Basically its reloading the same view its currently in with a new loadRequest and pushing it on top of the stack, so the user can go back to the last loadRequest.

Now with storyboard I can not figure out how to accomplish this same function with segue's, I need to invoke these actions and push the controller onto the stack.

I tried performSegueWithIdentifier but had no luck.

If I use a NSURL load request for the webview without pushing a new instance of the view controller on the stack, it works.

But I need the user to be able to go back.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I love "prepareForSegway"! Hilarious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebView`'s `goBack` method:

> **goBack**
>   Loads the previous location in the back-forward list.

You could add some buttons to accomplish this, in the nav bar or an extra toolbar. This is certainly better design than pushing a new view controller instance.

BTW, you can push a view controller onto itself via segues by dragging the segue to the very same view controller in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

And getting the storyboard item by its ID, and then using the old pushViewController.

Achieved the same effect.